# I want to make a container that has curve and borderRadius on its top

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, 40, size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
}
```

[image]

but when I add borderRadius it gets messed.

could you help me please?

I used clippath but I couldnt make it properly.when I make it i cant add borderRadius to be like the image.if you could write me the clip that makes that shape It will be amazing. but notice that the part border ends and curve begins is very importatnt.thank you

Comment: can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: how is that font named? looks nice

Comment: @MarcelDz sorry I dont know

Comment: Do you need shading/elevation ?

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh I have made the top curve but I cant use border radius beacue it gets meese at top right and left and it doexsnt get soft. I mean it gets sharp at the corners

Comment: can you share the full sample snippet for this

Comment: https://dribbble.com/shots/20142345-Weather-App @MDYeasinSheikh

Comment: please could you try this to see if you can make the container? @MDYeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your Container with `ClipPath` and use your path there.  Also, You can use `OutlinedBorder`

You can use this path.

```dart
class CustomShape extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final curve = 20.0;
    path.moveTo(0, curve);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, curve, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, curve * 2, size.width - curve, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, curve);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, you find more about [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution without using borderRadius.

```
child: CustomPaint(
  size: Size(WIDTH,(WIDTH*0.8).toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
  painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
),


class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  // Layer 1
  
  Paint paint_fill_0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = size.width*0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
     
         
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.2035000,size.height*0.8764000);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.8011000,size.height*0.8754000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.8577000,size.height*0.8608250,size.width*0.8755000,size.height*0.8197000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.9006000,size.height*0.7267000,size.width*0.8984600,size.height*0.2429000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.9002000,size.height*0.2875750,size.width*0.8977400,size.height*0.2446000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.9045800,size.height*0.0844500,size.width*0.6855800,size.height*0.1480000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.5994000,size.height*0.1706500,size.width*0.5039000,size.height*0.1734000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.4071000,size.height*0.1720250,size.width*0.2619800,size.height*0.1359000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.0952800,size.height*0.1110250,size.width*0.1025400,size.height*0.2254000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1019200,size.height*0.2595250,size.width*0.1003800,size.height*0.3059000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1093400,size.height*0.6714250,size.width*0.1183000,size.height*0.8098000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1252000,size.height*0.8580500,size.width*0.2035000,size.height*0.8764000);
    path_0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_fill_0);
  

  // Layer 1
  
  Paint paint_stroke_0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width*0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
     
    
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_stroke_0);
    
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).